# Converting UTC dates to other timezones

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

I'm converting a UTC time to another timezone, using this method:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date parsed = format.parse("2011-03-01 15:10:37");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
format.setTimeZone(tz);

String result = format.format(parsed);
```

So the input is `2011-03-01 15:10:37` but the output of this (value of result) is `2011-03-01 05:40:37`. While it seems off, and according to [this link](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/tzc.tzc), it should be `2011-03-01 09:10:37`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It turns out the code was almost correct, what I didn't take into account was that when parsing the `String` to get a `Date` object initially, it uses default system `TimeZone`, so the source date was not in UTC as I expected.

The trick was to set the timezone when parsing the date to UTC and then set it to destination `TimeZone`. Something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date parsed = sourceFormat.parse("2011-03-01 15:10:37"); // => Date is in UTC now

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

String result = destFormat.format(parsed);
```

Comment: don't forget the `try{} catch (ParseException e){}` around `sourceFormat.parse()`. Also, to get the local timezone that the phone is in then use `TimeZone.getDefault()` so that you can convert UTC to local timezone

Comment: @hadi Eskandari Mate you just saved me! I was tearing my hair out trying to figure this problem...! I pull down values from our server and store to a Database before i display to screen. The server dates are stored in AEST (Australian Eastern Standard) and I was having your exact problem where it was using the default system timezone so interpreting the time wrong. When i tried changing to another date it was always wrong :) I just needed `formater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(RBApplication.adjustTimezoneAEST));` before my parsing line. Cheers i was on this problem for a few hours!

Comment: the "HH" in SimpleDateFormat is for 24 hours and not for 12 hours, that ate up my 2 hours of debugging

Answer (score 14):

Converting a date String of the format "2011-06-23T15:11:32" to out time zone.

```
 private String getDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date value = null;
    try {
        value = formatter.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmaa");
    dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    String dt = dateFormatter.format(value);

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Following code works fine for me to change a date from one tz to another. It considers the DayLightSaving also.

```
public static Calendar changeTimezoneOfDate(Date date, TimeZone fromTZ, TimeZone toTZ) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long fromOffset = fromTZ.getOffset(millis);
    long toOffset = toTZ.getOffset(millis);
    long convertedTime = millis - (fromOffset - toOffset);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(convertedTime);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can Parse your date format and time zone according to your requirements.
Try this snippet of code i hope it helpful for you.

```
private String getFormattedDate(String OurDate) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); // According to your Server TimeStamp
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); //your Server Time Zone
        Date value = formatter.parse(OurDate); // Parse your date

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); //this format changeable according to your choice
        dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        OurDate = dateFormatter.format(value);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        OurDate = "00-00-0000 00:00";

    }
    return OurDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take Daylight Savings into consideration. I do this by working out the offset (from UTC) in millieseconds. Something like this should work.

```
int currentOffsetFromUTC = tz.getRawOffset() + (tz.inDaylightTime(parsed) ? tz.getDSTSavings() : 0);
String result = format.format(parsed.getTime() + currentOffsetFromUTC);
```

The `inDayLightTime(...)` method returns a boolean and must be passed a Date object in order for it to decide if that 'date' represents one during a DST period or not.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    ZoneId targetZone = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
    
    LocalDateTime parsed = LocalDateTime.parse("2011-03-01 15:10:37", formatter);
    ZonedDateTime converted = parsed.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZoneSameInstant(targetZone);

    String result = converted.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is the expected:

> 2011-03-01 09:10:37

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The simple sequence I settled for is to parse the UTC time into a `LocalDateTime` and then create a `ZonedDateTime` with the desired timezone. The resulting `ZonedDateTime` can be used to get an `Instant` to construct a new `Date` object.

In the example snippet below, One can replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with the desired time zone id.

```java
var instant = LocalDateTime.parse(serverDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")) //the current zone is UTC
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()) //the new time zone
                .toInstant();

var date = Date.from(instant);
```

NB: To use `LocalDateTime` in Android API level below 26, you can add [Android desugaring lib](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) to your codebase.